# Unity3D Sprite tearing on Android Smartphone

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites

The game was running on Samsung Galaxy Trend 2.

[image: Sprite glitch]

On other smaptphones and emulator it seems running properly without glitches.

Sprites import settings are following:

[image: Import Settings]

Could someone explain why this happens?
[image: Sprite tearing]

Comment: Are you getting the same result on other android phones? And did you try to change opengl version of your unity game? Or changing the Render parameters (options)

Comment: No,no,no. Thank you, i will change this parameters and then reply.

Comment: Not relevant, but for 2D games, uncheck "GEnerate Mip Maps"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

99.99% of the time "Generate Mip Map" is the culprit behind such problems.
Please switch of this option for all sprite import setting. This option is only needed for 3D objects where the engine can scale down the texture according to the z distance for performance optimization.

You can read more about Mip Maps in this link - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap